# Why does Ubuntu 18.04.1 completely freeze when watching a video

Tags: 18.04, vlc, smplayer

I tried streaming a movie from online to VLC, the computer froze after a while.
I tried playing a local movie in VLC, the computer froze after a while.
I tried playing a local movie in SMPlayer, the computer after a while.

Every time the computer froze, the image froze and I couldn't do anything (couldn't switch to a any program, I tried a bunch of shortcuts such as Ctrl+Alt+F1)but the sound kept on playing.

The computer would freeze after a random amount of time, but the only way I could unfreeze it is by holding the power button until the computer shut down.

I even tried updating the repositories by doing sudo apt-get update/upgrade but it didn't do anything.

My computer:
Ubuntu 18.04.1 with FDE
R5 2500u
8GB DDR4 dual channel
MX200 500GB SSD
1080p screen

I also had this laptop as dual boot Ubuntu and Windows for a while, without any issues. I did a fresh install to utilise full disk encryption.

If someone can provide me with help on how to solve this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Here is my VLC log:

```
-- logger module started --

main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

main: playlist is empty

-- logger module started --

main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

main: playlist is empty

glconv_vaapi_x11 error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error

-- logger module stopped --

-- logger module started --

main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

main: playlist is empty

glconv_vaapi_x11 error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error

-- logger module stopped --

-- logger module started --

main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

main: playlist is empty

glconv_vaapi_x11 error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As a first step, you could try to reproduce the bug with enabled log files in your VLC player. To do so, follow the steps indicated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/953266/94570

Comment: Im not sure if this is what your looking for, but this is what i found in the logger.                                   
                                                           glconv_vaapi_x11 error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error

Comment: Check out this post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/99unhl/computer_keeps_freezing_whenever_i_play_a_video/

Comment: Lmfao, I made that post on Reddit. You can even see that this askubuntu thread is linked to it!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered several of these freezes recently on a laptop (trackpad). I used to think that the only way I could unfreeze it was by holding the power button until the computer shut down.

However, when I connect a USB mouse, the laptop unfreezes. Perhaps more of a workaround than a solution, but I suppose it is more practical than shutting down every time the computer freezes.