# Video playback occasionally freezes UI and keyboard

Tags: 18.04, video, playback

As stated, when playing <s>avi</s> video files with <s>vlc</s> video player (no matter - fullscreen or windowed) after some time (10 to 30 minutes, seems to be somehow tied to screen dim):

- picture on screen freezes
- keyboard hangs

  - cant turn off numlock
  - ctrl+alt+whatever not working
- sometimes I can move mouse, but it cannot interact with ubuntu top panel.
- pressing power button has no effect
- audio remains playing as normal (till the end of movie)

So that's not a kernel hang, and not an app hang... but UI + USB input freeze!
THE Only way to continue look movie is to press reset button.

Browsing works well, no Chrome crashes, in-browser youtube could show videos for hours. There is enough memory, less than 20% used. none of 2GB swap used. Movie files are always in RAM (/mnt/tmp/somefile.mkv, on tmpfs), RAM was checked several times, memtest ok, Chrome tabs has NOT crashed even once!

---

### H/W:

- CPU: i7 920
- RAM: 48 gigs ram
- GPU: ATI R9 270 2Gb
- monitor: 2k 75hz IPS panel, attached via DP1.2
- usb 2.0 generic keyboard and mouse

---

### S/W:

**`uname -a`**

`Linux apc 4.18.0-22-generic #23~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 08:37:25 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**`lsb_release -a`**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**`vlc --version`**

```
VLC media player 3.0.7 Vetinari (revision 3.0.7-0-g86cee31)
VLC version 3.0.7 Vetinari (3.0.7-0-g86cee31)
Compiled by jenkins on e672859d050d (Jun  7 2019 10:27:35)
Compiler: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
```

**`lshw -c video`**

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fbd80000-fbdbffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**`modinfo amdgpu | grep version`**

```
version:        5.0.19.20.7
```

---

### Steps taken, to reproduce hang:

- dowload Ubuntu 18.04.2  from [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=RU&version=18.04.2&architecture=amd64)
- Erase and Clean install (one partiton, minimal install + upgrades + 3rdparty)
- amdgpu-pro (I need opencl) drivers 19.20 downloaded from [their page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-20-unified)
- Installed with `./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy`
- Reboot
- `sudo snap install VLC`
- Open avi file (xvid codec)
- 20 minute = screen freeze, UI dead, only sound will remain playing till the end of movie.

---

### Questions

- What could be wrong?
- How to investigate?
- Has someone else encountered same problems with 18.04+vlc+amdgpu ?

---

### Search effort taken

- Found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391321), but it is related to nvidia hardware
- Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068398/why-does-ubuntu-18-04-1-completely-freeze-when-watching-a-video), but no solution was found

---

### <s>Temporary solution</s>

`sudo apt install mplayer mplayer-gui`

<s>This works great..</s>

After a day of testing: 
Nope, it also could hang. 
Removing the VLC tag. 
Problem is somewhere in Ubuntu/Xorg/OpenGL/video drivers

---

### Conclusions

I've found it much more convenient to use linux console for software building process, but its wet/unstable UX just've disappointed me, in its everyday/recreational use.

I just wanted to watch a movie! For a couple of days using it (I mean X.Org and ALSA) I alredy had to:

- reinstall OS/gpu drivers couple of times
- encounter dropouts/silence problems with "sound via display port"
- numerous freezes and crashes of popular software

These two technologies, that are barebones of user interaction - are real  beta-versions of something, that may be ever human-usable! Random freezes, screen-flashes, sound dropouts... 2019-th? Most user-friendly desktop distro? LOL.. that wood is too raw wet, to become a good easy-to-set fire yet, guys!

Comment: Am having similar problem. I7(8700), 16GB, 1TB HDD, Acer desktop stock from factory, 18.04 fully up to date. However, my VLC *only* freezes in full screen mode (and *always* freeze in full screen mode after less than a minute but audio continues, cannot use keyboard, must power down).

Comment: Did you try running the shell command `vlc --nooverlay` in order to make VLC start with disabled hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in my case root caouse was in malfunctioning gpu, R9 390x i've previously used it for mining (when ETH was a joke for $10) and it seems that it was malfunctioning in weird way. By replacing with same gpu (It was from mining as well, but more lucky one) problem gone.. now i am using 20.04 on a top build with 10980xe and fast ddr4, and i had to say that OS is very weak to hardware instability - until i changed my ram set from a buggy to a stable one (seems is also matter of silicon luck) ubuntu software tended to crash periodically..