# mplayer running video slow

Tags: video, video-player, mplayer

I have tried several video players and they all seem to not play back the video at the correct frame rate. It is very slow and almost at a stand still.

The following feedback could be gained from the command-line:

```
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing GH010031_reduced.mp4.
libavformat version 57.83.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f900dc762a0]Protocol name not provided, cannot determine if input is local or a network protocol, buffers and access patterns cannot be configured optimally without knowing the protocol
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang eng
VIDEO:  [H264]  720x540  24bpp  59.940 fps  465.8 kbps (56.9 kbyte/s)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[VO_XV] It seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
[VO_XV] Run 'xvinfo' to verify its Xv support and read
[VO_XV] DOCS/HTML/en/video.html#xv!
[VO_XV] See 'mplayer -vo help' for other (non-xv) video out drivers.
[VO_XV] Try -vo x11.
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 encoder: Lavf58.20.100
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 129.4 kbit/4.21% (ratio: 16172->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [x11] 720x540 => 720x540 Planar YV12 
[swscaler @ 0x7f900e13e020]bicubic scaler, from yuv420p to bgra using MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 0x7f900e13e020]using unscaled yuv420p -> bgra special converter
A:   0.5 V:   0.6 A-V: -0.069 ct:  0.012   0/  0 16% 16%  0.2% 0 0
```

running `xvinfo` I get:

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
 no adaptors present
```

running `mplayer -vo help`

```
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
Available video output drivers:
    vdpau   VDPAU with X11
    xv  X11/Xv
    gl_nosw OpenGL no software rendering
    x11 X11 ( XImage/Shm )
    xover   General X11 driver for overlay capable video output drivers
    sdl SDL YUV/RGB/BGR renderer (SDL v1.1.7+ only!)
    gl  OpenGL
    gl_tiled    X11 (OpenGL) - multiple textures version
    dga DGA ( Direct Graphic Access V2.0 )
    fbdev   Framebuffer Device
    fbdev2  Framebuffer Device
    matrixview  MatrixView (OpenGL)
    aa  AAlib
    caca    libcaca
    v4l2    V4L2 MPEG Video Decoder Output
    directfb    Direct Framebuffer Device
    dfbmga  DirectFB / Matrox G200/G400/G450/G550
    xvidix  X11 (VIDIX)
    cvidix  console VIDIX
    null    Null video output
    xvmc    XVideo Motion Compensation
    mpegpes MPEG-PES to DVB card
    yuv4mpeg    yuv4mpeg output for mjpegtools
    png PNG file
    jpeg    JPEG file
    gif89a  animated GIF output
    tga Targa output
    pnm PPM/PGM/PGMYUV file
    md5sum  md5sum of each frame
```

`lspci` shows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0c.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Did you try VLC?

Comment: @singrium I did. It returns the following error: `Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///blabla/GH010031_reduced.mp4'. Check the log for details.`

Comment: Hmm, may be there is a problem with your file, may it is corrupted. And what does the log contain?

Comment: @singrium. This file plays perfectly on windows.

Comment: @singrium. I tried to find out where the log lives but haven't been able to.

Comment: Check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910037/where-is-the-vlc-logfile-for-errors) to see where the VLC logs are stored.

Comment: Seems like you're somehow missing hardware support for your video card. Do you actually have a NVidia card? See `lspci`, and if in doubt add the output to your question. What about reinstalling the drivers?

Comment: @Murphy. I am running ubuntu 18.04 in a virtualbox on a windows 10 host. Will add the lspci output.

Comment: For appropriate video support in VirtualBox you need to [install the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/a/792833/568304).