# VLC cannot play video file located on mounted network share

Tags: video, vlc

I have a network share which mounts at startup on Ubuntu 18.04.3. I can list and play any of the video files with the Ubuntu movie app, however when I try to play them with VLC I get the following error:

**Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/ruscat/Videos/Movies/101%20Dalmations/101%20Dalmations.avi'. Check the log for details.**

How can I correct this problem?  Any help gladly accepted.

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the share using the  Local Network menu in VLC?

Comment: No.I’ll give this a try when I get home from work.

Comment: Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/bAQLlvW

Comment: Can you put the log file details ?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/910037/where-is-the-vlc-logfile-for-errors